# Scheduled SSIS task hanging on execute process task

Tags: ssis, scheduled-tasks, ssms, sql-server-agent, sql-server-data-tools

Hi we have a SSIS package that calls an execute process task.
The task accesses a saved sql file in the directory, the agent that runs our task does have permission to access all these files. Yet when the package is executed it hangs at the execute process task, no processes are running but the package still is, all the previous tasks complete successfully until it reaches the execute process task

Comment: What does it do when it accesses the file ? Or rather what should it do.

Comment: i found the problem the cmd window doesnt show and it hit an exception where it required user input so it would never end or let the package continue but thank you for wanting to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if anyone is looking for the same problem we came across the answer, the cmd window required user input and therefore could not continue with the process until the cmd process task has finished and it never does.

So in short make sure your cmd process doesnt require user input if you are deploying to SSISDB or it will hang and you cant do anything about it